# Cannot upload img to a folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im using laravel. And the img wont upload to my public/imgs folder. It keeps saying Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

```
// PHP CODE
$target_dir = "public/imgs/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["name"], $target_file)) {
     echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}

// HTML CODE
<form method="POST" action="/listings" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img">
</form>
```

Comment: try `echo 'sorry (upload failed) ' . $_FILES['img']['error'];` and see the reference here http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: i think you should write the complete path from the root path (like: /var/www/public/imgs) unless of course if public is already at the root path

Comment: @vee when i did that it said . sorry (upload failed) 0

 i tried that  already jacky

Comment: @Jeff99 then it means your upload is not really error, it's error in `move_uploaded_file` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

use `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)` instead of `["name"]`

Comment: @vee when I do that it says. ErrorException (E_WARNING)
move_uploaded_file(/public/imgs/logo2.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jeff99 The `$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]` should be something in temp folder not public/imgs/logo2.png

You can make sure that it is really exists with `is_file` function. Example: `if (is_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) {move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_file);} else {echo 'uploaded tmp file is not exists.';}`

Please make sure that you write it correctly `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']` NOT `$_FILES['img']['name']`.

Comment: have a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files. Not sure why you  are using native php when laravel has provided with elegant file upload. You can follow this tute http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/04/08/processing-file-uploads-with-laravel-5/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your original `move_uploaded_file` function to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)
```

[See the diff between name and tmp_name](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: It still had the same error. Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: does imgs directory exist?

Comment: That doesnt work because userfile is suppose to be named img.  b/c my form input name is img.  <input type="file" name="img">

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the upload dir is existing and writable; then file_uploads is on in php.ini

Comment: You can use public_path('') to get the right upload dir in laravel. And the $file = request->file() to get the upload file, then $file->move() to move

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="/listings" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img">
</form>
```

HTML

```
$target_dir = "public/imgs/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
if ($_FILES['img']['error'] == 0) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'upload failed<br>';
        echo '<pre>';
        echo 'tmp name: ';
        print_r($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
        echo "\n target: ".$target_file;
        echo "\n\n";
        print_r($_FILES['img']);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'upload failed: ' . $_FILES['img']['error'];
}
```

PHP

This code should work and show all data for debugging.